# Excel VBA Loop through sections of texts separated by blank space then copy and transpose onto a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I will like code that can cycle through a worksheet and copy and transpose each section onto another worksheet.

I have code that uses SpecialCells but have had issues with it. I would prefer code that uses Shift+Down then Shift+Right  `.End(xlDown)` `.End(xlToRight)`.

Here is the code that worked but I had issues when there were blanks in any of the cells. This code copies each area, only need column B and column C then pastes it into worksheet CombinedAndTransposed

```
    Sub Copy_Transpose_All_Sections()
    Dim Ra As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'B:C 2nd And 3rd Columns to copy
    For Each Ra In Columns("B:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas '23
        Ra.Copy
        Worksheets("CombinedAndTransposed").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next Ra
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The data is in the 2nd and 3rd column and is separated with blank rows.

The result should take each section of text and transpose it.

My code above works only when there is data in all cells within a section, but fails if any are missing or any formatting of the cells change.

Comment: So please show us the code that you tried with `.End(xlDown) and .End(xlRight)`

Comment: I only have code with the SpecialCells. I think using the .End code is what I need but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Plenty of examples on stackoverflow

Comment: I can see how they work but I can not figure out a way to get them to work in a loop where it will go down to each section and copy and paste back and forth from each sheet.

Comment: @cartoom02 Note that it is `xlDown` and `xlUp` but `xlToRight` and `xlToLeft` (with an additional `To`)!

Comment: Updated in the question @Pᴇʜ

Answer (score 0):

This is much more efficient.

```
Private Sub Answer ()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim source As Range
        Set source = .Range("B1", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim destination As Range
        Set destination = .Range("B1")
    End With

    ' Loop every odd row in range.
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 1 To source.Rows.Count Step 2
        ' Must resize destination range to match source. Transpose data from row to column.
        destination.Resize(source.Rows(row).Cells.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(source.Rows(row))
        ' Set destination to offset with a gap between data.
        Set destination = destination.Offset(destination.Cells.Count + 2)
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the paste put everything into a single row instead of having each section in its own rows.

Comment: @cartoom02 So you want column "B" to be copied into one row, and column C copied into the next row, correct? If not, what is your desired outcome?

Comment: I would like column b and column c to be copied into 2 rows respectively for each section. The code above puts them all into the same 2 rows not separate rows per section

Comment: @cartoom02 I edited my answer. If I understand correctly you are looking to group row data from columns b&c and put them together into a single row on a new sheet. Let me know if my edited code helps. Thanks